# Why wont my function add lists properly?

Tags: python, list, function, merge, addition

This is the function i wrote for a program, its supposed to move a value a spot down a list.

def moveCard(deck):

```
    index = deck.index(27) 
    deck.pop(index) 
    left = deck[:index+1] 
    right = deck[index+1:] 
    left.append(27) 

    print (left + right)

    deck = left + right
```

however it doesn't properly add the two lists unless i print it within the function it self.

running the funtion using text list cards = [24, 27, 2, 5, 8, 11] prints out the proper list, being [24, 2, 27, 5, 8, 11]. However if i then simply ask for the value of cards after running the method i get 
 [24, 2, 5, 8, 11]. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT 
this is my function:

def move_joker_1(deck):

```
    index = deck.index(JOKER1) 
    deck.pop(index) 
    left = deck[:index+1] 
    right = deck[index+1:] 
    left.append(JOKER1) 

    deck = left + right
    print(left + right)
    print(dec
```

This is what i type into shel/results:

cards = [24, 27, 2, 5, 8, 11]

move_joker_1(cards)

[24, 2, 27, 5, 8, 11]

[24, 2, 27, 5, 8, 11]

print(cards)

[24, 2, 5, 8, 11]

Comment: Can you fix your indentation so it matches your code? Are the `print` and `deck = …` lines part of the `moveCard` function, or not?

Comment: Also, instead of describing what you do to test it in English, can you show that in code? What does "simply ask for the value of the cards" mean?

Comment: @abarnert i edited it, is this ok??

Comment: First, don't add an `EDIT:` at the end with a different version of the same info. Just edit it. If people want to see the old versions, they can click on the history. Second, you have to format your code as code. Select it, and click the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your problem is this:

Inside the `moveCard` function, you've got a parameter named `deck`. First you do this:

```
deck.pop(index)
```

That's modifying the actual list that was passed in, so the caller is going to see that.

Then, later:

```
deck = left + right
```

That isn't modifying anything; it's creating a new list, `left + right`, and changing the local variable `deck` to be a name for that new list instead of for the old one.

---

What you probably want to do here is *return* the new list, so the caller can store it wherever he wants. But in that case, you don't want to mutate the original list with `pop`.

Alternatively, you could modify the list in-place both times, e.g., by writing `deck[:] = left + right`.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit: you are not modifying the `cards` list. You should put a `return` statement in your function and then call the function as follows: `cards = move_joker_1(cards)`.